# Please help clean up the ambiguous Apple iWork Tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Apple has cleverly named their iWork products "Pages", "Numbers" and "Keynote".

We therefore have three tags:

- [pages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pages), currently 69 tagged, mostly **very ambiguous**
- [keynote](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keynote), currently 34 tagged, all about Apple Keynote
- [iwork-numbers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iwork-numbers), currently 22 tagged, and obviously better than just [numbers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/numbers), which I've eliminated

---

I therefore suggest introducing the new tags:

- [iwork-pages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iwork-pages) ← manually retag questions from [pages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pages), or remove unnecessary "pages" from Qs and then automatically retag
- **Update:** Remove [the synonym](https://superuser.com/tags/pages/synonyms) for [iwork-pages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iwork-pages) → [pages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pages). It does not make sense, as "pages" is misused and ambiguous.
- [iwork-keynote](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iwork-keynote) ← Just automatically retag all [keynote](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keynote) Qs to this one

Comment: Agreed.  Any really common word that is the same name as another application should be prefixed by either the developer or software library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [keynote](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keynote) is now [iwork-keynote](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iwork-keynote)
- [iwork-pages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iwork-pages) is no longer a synonym of [pages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pages)

Retagging of [pages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pages) will have to be done manually. Let me know when you're removed it from all the questions it doesn't really belong on, and I'll merge it with [iwork-pages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iwork-pages).

Comment: I now did it a bit differently. I've manually retagged everything to `[iwork-pages]`, this means the remaining questions are left with `[pages]` (whatever that means). Therefore: **No need to merge**. I think we're done :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, well, for my part I feel strongly that [pages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pages) is an utterly meaningless tag after browsing through it -- and I have opted to destroy it after the disambiguation.